# Adobe Flex to erlang connectivity?

Tags: apache-flex, erlang

Has anyone gotten Adobe Flex and erlang to connect to each other?  A number of people talk about this on various blogs, but I haven't seen a working solution yet.

Flex and erlang would form a real best-of-breed combination.

Thanks.

Dean

Answer (score 2):

I haven't but I have thought about a few potential options:

- AMF - ErlAMF - http://code.google.com/p/erlamf/
- JSON - as3corelib has JSON http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer, it is probably going to be rolling your own AMF transport or using http/rest type API's, but this blog post from Ted Patrick may give you a place to start:

http://www.onflex.org/ted/2008/01/why-erlang.php

Comment: I saw Ted's blog.  He makes the case for Flex-erlang connectivity, but just lets you hanging with no answers.

Comment: Yeah, but some of the comments might give you some clues.  Also did you try to ping Ted directly?  He is generally fairly responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted my erlang-http server with flex remoting module and examples on github.

```
git clone git://github.com/mujaheed/erlang-http.git
cd erlang-http
git submodule init
git submodule update
make
cd examples/stock
make run
```

Then point your browser to http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

Flex front-end and RESTful back-end works well - with a socket to run your remoting.

The socket example can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/jssockets/).

Answer (score 0):

I think [Vimagi](http://vimagi.com/) combines Flash/Flex? with Erlang.